# Windows 10 Network Adapter Status

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, internet-connection

I've got an interesting issue.  My network adapter in Windows 10 shows as "No Internet" intermittently, even when there is internet.  I have to assume that this is somehow related to my recent string of internet disconnections, but it's really hard to say.  I also assume that it's related to my VPN usage.  I am currently in China on business and will be here until Q3.  When I enable VPN, the connection shows as wired(connected) regardless of my actual connection type.  What is wrong here?  Why does it show as not connected when it is?  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my WLAN driver (not Ethernet but the following resolution might work similar) in Windows 10. A trick I use to come along is to deactivate the respective driver in the [Device-Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) applet and than later reactivate it again.

I don´t know, if this might help you in the way it has helped me, but you should give it a try at least.